# Is property binding really a one way binding?

Tags: angular, binding

I am new to Angular and started tutorials. From tutorial, Angular property binding is one way binding (at least in this case). So change in property of HeroComponent should change property of HeroDetailComponent but changing property of HeroDetailComponent is changing property of HeroComponent.

From Ref [doc](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3)

> It's a one way data binding from the selectedHero property of the HeroesComponent to the hero property of the target element, which maps to the hero property of the HeroDetailComponent.

Sample code

1. heroes.component.html

   {{selectedHero}}

   <app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero">
2. heroes.detail.component.ts

   export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() hero: Hero;
   }
3. heroes.detail.component.html

   <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>

Complete code [at](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3)

Comment: Not sure what the question is.. but basically, because you’re using [(ngModel)] here, is has become 2-way binding.

Comment: [(ngModel)] is a 2 way binding, so I understnad change of hero in `heroes.detail.component.html` will change hero in `heroes.detail.component.ts` but why also change of hero in `heroes.component.html` (parent component / template) after all <app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"> is a oe way binding.

Comment: Because it is the same object.. passed by reference.

Comment: Then why does it say property binding is a one way data binding

Answer (score 0):

Because of [unidirectional data flow](https://angular.io/guide/glossary#unidirectional-data-flow)